# Move or copy selective files, while recreating directory structure

Tags: command-line, find, rsync, xargs, gnu

I'm looking for a command or commandline that can **take a list of files** of a subtree (via a pipe, etc.) and copy/**move them to a new destination**, while **recreating the source directory structure**.

1. It should preserve all the relevant file attributes; including timestamps, xattrs and hardlinks.
2. The newly recreated directories should also "keep" their timestamps (using `touch` or something).

In my specific scenario, I'm using `fdupes` to find duplicates between two source trees `a` and `b`, whereas I then want to move the duplicates in tree `a` elsewhere while preserving their directory structure.
But for simplicity, the output of `find . -type f` produces the input I want to work with. (Just understand that "use rsync" is not a solution I can use -- I think.)

I feel I need to write a slightly elaborate `find | xargs / while read line` loop, but perhaps I'm missing a cool tool and someone has a better solution using `rename` or the likes (or already has a script like this they can share)?

Much appreciated!

Example input:

```
cat <<THEEND | <program-or-script> /target/directory/
./subtree/with/a/file
./subtree/with/some/other/file
./subtree/with/even/more/files
THEEND
```

Wanted result:

```
$ find /target/directory/ -type f
/target/directory/subtree/with/a/file
/target/directory/subtree/with/some/other/file
/target/directory/subtree/with/even/more/files
```

It should **not** copy or move a hypothetical `./subtree/with/an/ignored/file` from the source tree.
(It also doesn't need to clean up any empty directories remaining in the source tree.)

Comment: Why is rsync not an option for you? No other tool is more suited for your issue.

Comment: @guest_7, I'd love to use rsync. Can you give an example?